# I am purchasing cvc through shapeshift. where is my ethe return address

Tags: tokens, exchanges, shapeshift

I am purchasing cvc through shapeshift. Shapeshift is asking me my ethe refund address. do have to create one? or.....

Answer (score 1):

If your transaction goes through but exchange (partly) fails for whatever reason (such as you sent too much, not enough, or were too slow to send), your refund address is where your leftover ether is sent. It's there for your benefit, but you don't have to fill it in. You can just put the address you are sending from if you want to be safe.

Comment: So as you can see I am new to this....so I cut and pasted the cvc address to the site. Now it is saying what is your refund address.....this is where I am confused. where do i get the refund address or what is the refund address? and then once it transactions goes through, where are my cvc shares?

Comment: If you are exchanging ETH to CVC, then your refund address is where any unconverted ETH is sent (see answer above). You can use the ETH account used to send ETH as your refund address. Your CVC goes to the address you provide for CVC.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh....dude you are the man....!!! So I have to create a refund address for the CVC to be deposited...Where the hell do you create that....myetherwallet or something like that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to your setup. What are you using to store your ether? What were you planning on using to store CVC before you posted here? (It's okay if you hadn't figured that out... just trying to figure out what you need to do to move forwards).

Comment: Dude thats just it. I do not know where to store the cvc, once I purchase it, where does it go...where is the cvc sent to? I have accounts with a couple sites where I have purchased and hold bitcoin and ethereum. I am trying to figure out the coin exchange once I purchase cvc where they send my cvc. Do I need to set up a wallet with and address for them to send it to.

Comment: Since you're starting from square one, the easiest way to get CVC is probably to install the Jaxx wallet from https://jaxx.io. I use this wallet on my phone, but you should do your own research as to whether it is safe and secure for your own use. You can send cryptocurrencies from an exchange to the address provided by the wallet and then use the built-in exchange functionality (Jaxx does exchanges through Shapeshift.io) to convert some ether/coins to CVC tokens. Don't forget to back up your Jaxx keys.